# Certificate showing up as invalid even though the domain name matches

Tags: domain-name-system, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

We just bought a certificate for files.website.com. We have installed it to the file transfer software we are using (Globalscape EFT) but are still getting an error message saying "The site's security certificate is not trusted!"

I go to view the certificate from the browser and the domain name matches exactly with the name in the certificate.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may need to supply an intermediate certificate to complete a chain of trust, but without knowing more its difficult to say. Can you clarify what you mean by "installed it to the file transfer software we are using". Can you elaborate on the the steps you have took to install this certificate?

Comment: These are pretty handy diagnostic tools: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ .

Comment: If you provide the domain it may be easier to check this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns we had to download the intermediate certificates and combine them with the signed certificate. This combination of certificates fixed the issue.

Thanks for all of the responses.